# Nexus-prisma: order nested connections

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

What is the best way to keep order of nested objects in the schema.

My schema:

```
type Article {
  id: ID! @id
  pages: [Page!]!
}

type Page {
  id: ID! @id
}
```

This is how I'm trying to sort the pages(unsuccessfully):

```
  updateArticle({
    variables: {
      aricle.id,
      data: {
        pages: {
          connect: reorderPages(aricle.pages)
        }
      }
    }
```

The resolver:

```
 t.field("updateArticle", {
      type: "Article",
      args: {
        id: idArg(),
        data: t.prismaType.updateArticle.args.data
      },
      resolve: (_, { id, data }) => {
        return ctx.prisma.updateArticle({
          where: { id },
          data
        });
      }
    });
```

I understand why this approach is wrong. I guess that the order should be written in the database by an order index in the connection table. I don't know how to process that by GraphQL/Nexus/Prisma/MySQL.

Comment: Why are you not using the orderBy argument?

Comment: So do you please mean to update all the nested object with an order index and then sort them by orderBy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For N:M to relations the schema would look like this:

```
type Article {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  items: [ArticleItemEdge!]! 
}

type ArticleItemEdge {
  id: ID! @id
  article: Article! @relation(link: INLINE)
  item: Item! @relation(link: INLINE)
  order: Int!
}

type Item {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  articles: [ArticleItemEdge!]!
}
```

And then query articles in a more "Relay" like fashion with edges & nodes

```
query {
  articles {
    items(orderBy: order_ASC) {
      item {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

And if N:M isn't needed, you can update the schema definition like so:

```
type Article {
  id: ID! @id
  items: [Item!]!
}

type Item {
  id: ID! @id
  article: Article! @relation(link: INLINE)
  order: Int!
}
```

^ this will turn the db tables into 1:N relation ship rather than n:m

Then you can issue a query like so:

```
query {
  articles {
    id
    items(orderBy: order_ASC) {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Updating the value of the "order" should be straight forward so I'll omit it here.

Hope it answers your question!